# Openlayers: Change the icon of the full-screen-true button

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome, openlayers

I changed the openlayers (v6.3.1) controls icons to custom icons using Font Awesome and jquery:

```
$('button.ol-full-screen-true').html('<i class="fas fa-compress"></i>');
$('button.ol-full-screen-false').html('<i class="fas fa-expand"></i>');
```

This works as intended for the `full-screen-false` button. But the `full-screen-true` button does not change if I toggle full screen. Instead it uses the `full-screen-false` Font Awesome icon. If I remove the code for the `full-screen-false` icon, the default icons are shown. I also tried to change the tooltips of both buttons. It also worked only for the `full-screen-false` control.

I am stuck here and can't think of (or find) any other solution.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan I did indeed. I created an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a different, more complex, solution.

```
var fullscreenFalse = document.createElement('i');
fullscreenFalse.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-expand');
var fullscreenTrue = document.createElement('i');
fullscreenTrue.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-compress');

var fullscreen = new ol.control.FullScreen({
    source: document.getElementById('map').parentNode,
    label: fullscreenFalse,
    labelActive: fullscreenTrue
});
```

You can change the tooltips using the following code:

```
fullscreen.on('enterfullscreen', function(evt){
    $('button.ol-full-screen-true').attr('title', 'Leave fullscreen');
});
fullscreen.on('leavefullscreen', function(evt){
    $('button.ol-full-screen-false').attr('title', 'Enter fullscreen');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, but there is a small typescript trick. There are errors such as: `Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'string | Text'.` The error disappears when I use  `as any` for objects properties(please check comment below). Could you recommend solution for that?

Comment: Like this:                                                                                                                              
  let fullScreenControl = new FullScreen({
      source: document.getElementById('map').parentNode as any,
      label: fullscreenFalse as any,
      labelActive: fullscreenTrue as any,
    });